# OTRS login via REST API

Tags: rest, authentication, otrs

I am trying to authenticate to our OTRS 7 deployment via REST. Unfortunately I am not too familiar with the technology and so I suspect, that I have problems with the JSON syntax.

As described in the official [documentation](https://doc.otrs.com/doc/api/otrs/7.0/REST/), I am sending my request to "/api/customer/auth/login"

I tried sending the following:

```
"username": "myUser",
"password": "myPassword"
}
```

and this as well

```
{
   "properties": {
      "username": "myUser",
      "password": "myPassword"
   }
}
```

But I only get responses like this

```
{
  "Errors": {
    "password": [
      {
        "Attributes": {
          "Arguments": [],
          "Source": "myPassword",
          "Value": "myPassword"
        },
        "Validator": "UnknownValue"
      }
    ],
    "username": [
      {
        "Attributes": {
          "Arguments": [],
          "Source": "myUser",
          "Value": "myUser"
        },
        "Validator": "UnknownValue"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can't seem to get any meaningful response.

Does anyone have a JSON snippet for a successful login? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't send this info as JSON post... it will be rather a basic auth, where you need to send this info in the according header, I would say.